# Copy from text file to Object type arrayList in Java

Tags: java, text, arraylist

I'm making a student system with console based java. I'm trying to load a text file's content to an ArrayList and later on search with a student registration number and list down his/her name and program.
I'm having a hard time loading the text file contents in an ArrayList so that I can retrieve them later on as objects.

I have made a search function that works perfectly on an Arraylist (Since when entering a new record I am putting them in ArrayList and they can be searched until the program is not shut)

**This is the approach I am using trying to load the text file in an ArrayList:**

```
try {
    ArrayList<NewStudent> student = new ArrayList<>(); 
    BufferedReader  inFile = new BufferedReader (new FileReader ("Test.txt"));
    String inputLine;

    while ((inputLine = inFile.readLine())!=null) { 
        NewStudent ns = new NewStudent();
        String[] studentVars = inputLine.split(":"); 
        ns.setName(studentVars[0]);

        student.add(ns);
    }
    System.out.print(student);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**This is my approach in searching and this works like a charm**

```
public Student Search(String ID, ArrayList<Student> StudentList) {
    Student myStudent = new Student();

    for(int i=0 ; i<StudentList.size() ; i++) {
        if(StudentList.get(i).getID().equals(ID)) {
            myStudent.setID(StudentList.get(i).getID());
            myStudent.setName(StudentList.get(i).getName());
            myStudent.setProgram(StudentList.get(i).getProgram());

            return myStudent;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

**When it prints, it prints this:**

> > [com.Student.NewStudent@615e7597, com.Student.NewStudent@7a3e72, com.Student.NewStudent@5999ae9c, >>com.Student.NewStudent@7896b1b8, com.Student.NewStudent@6d6de4e1, com.Student.NewStudent@49cda7e7, com.Student.NewStudent@5cca548b]

**And if I use a different approach that is:**

```
BufferedReader inFile = new BufferedReader (new FileReader ("Student.txt"));
ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
String inputLine;
while ( (inputLine = inFile.readLine() ) != null) {
    String[] stud = inputLine.split(":"); 
    arrayList.add(stud[0]); \\if I add stud[1] it gives null pointer exception
}
System.out.println(arrayList);
```

This doesn't return as separate objects. it shows one straight line

**This is how my text file looks like**

1112149
Alexx
BSCS

1112155
Tamara
BSCS

1112154
Kathy
BBA

1112114
John
BABS

**Every object is on different line**

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: What is your code supposed to do?  What does it actually do?

Comment: I forgot to write the problem. Now I've edited it. If only people would give us newbies some time before downvoting

Comment: In first case you are creating `arraylist` of objects of type `NewStudent`. In second one, you are just creating `arraylist` of `String`. So obviously there wont be any objects and just strings will be printed out

Comment: @GoldRoger I'm using that string in a setName setter of my Student Bean Class

Comment: replace `String[] stud = inputLine.split(":");` by     `String[] stud = inputLine.split(" ");` because there is no semi-colon in your text file.

Comment: @SujanSivagurunathan took care of that already

Comment: Why are printing the objects `arrayList` and `student` and not the string value of their elements/fields ?

Comment: @SujanSivagurunathan because later on I have to search a record with its ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: You trying to split on :, but i dont see any : in the textfile ?

change

1112149 Alexx BSCS

1112155 Tamara BSCS

1112154 Kathy BBA

1112114 John BABS

to

1112149:Alexx:BSCS

1112155:Tamara:BSCS

1112154:Kathy:BBA

1112114:John:BABS

and then use the following code:

```
try {

   ArrayList<NewStudent> student = new ArrayList<>(); 
   BufferedReader inFile = new BufferedReader (new FileReader("Test.txt"));
   String inputLine;

   while ((inputLine = inFile.readLine())!=null) { 

      if(inputLine.isEmpty()) continue; //i dont know if you have blank lines between students in txt, if so. use this line of code.

      NewStudent ns = new NewStudent();
      String[] studentVars = inputLine.split(":"); 
      ns.setId(studentVars[0]);
      ns.setName(studentVars[1]);
      ns.setProgram(studentVars[2]);

      System.out.println("ID: " + studentVars[0] + " Name: " + studentVars[1] + " Program: " + studentVars[2])

      student.add(ns);
}
   //or you could use this to loop and print all items in Arraylist.
   for(NewStudent nStudent : student) {
      System.out.println(nStudent.getId() + " " + nStudent.getName() + " " + nStudent.getProgram());
   }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: This is the result of this. null
1112149, Alexx, BSCSnullnull
nullnull
1112155, Tamara, BSCSnullnull
nullnull
1112154, Kathy, BBAnullnull
nullnull
1112114, John, BABSnull

Comment: Paste how your txt file looks like...

Comment: Check the edit. I have posted it. Please note that all objects are in different lines

Comment: Okay, I changed everything as you said but it's still giving me the null things.

Comment: I'm not using any int value. All of them are Strings

Comment: Okey. Ive updated my post again.

Comment: What will happen when you have blank lines ? Did you think about it, and the while loop ?

Comment: @Henrik the approach you used just now, I've tried that before too. For some weird reason, its giving null pointer exception :(

Comment: Remove blank lines in your text file or change your while loop so it takes count of the blank lines.

Comment: @Henrik  File file = new File("Test.txt");
     ArrayList<NewStudent> records = new ArrayList<NewStudent>();
     Scanner in = new Scanner(file);  
     while (in.hasNextLine()){
      NewStudent ns = new NewStudent();
      ns.setRegNo(in.nextLine());
      ns.setName(in.nextLine());
      ns.setProgram(in.nextLine());
    records.add(ns);
     }
     for(NewStudent nStudent : records) {
           System.out.println(nStudent.getRegNo());
           System.out.print(nStudent.getName());
           System.out.print(nStudent.getProgram());
        }